# How to check multiple conditons in a IF statement

Tags: shell-script, test

I am trying to test for multiple conditions in the following `if` statement:

```
If [[[ "$var1" = "$var2" || "$var1" = "$var3" || "$var1" = "$var4" ]]];
```

However, when I execute the above mentioned syntax I am getting an error. Can anyone help me in getting multiple conditions checking in IF statement?

Answer (score 4):

You have too many brackets, and the `if` should not be capitalized.  Try like this:

```
if [[ "$var1" == "$var2" || "$var1" == "$var3" || "$var1" == "$var4" ]]; then
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be easier to use the standard `sh` syntax rather than that (mispelled, it should be `[[` instead of `[[[`) `ksh` construct:

```
case $var1 in
  "$var2" | "$var3" | "$var4") echo match;;
  *) echo no match;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ "$var1" == "$var2" || "$var1" == "$var3" || "$var1" == "$var4" ]]
```

or, for readability,

```
[[ "$var1" == "$var2" ]] ||
[[ "$var1" == "$var3" ]] ||
[[ "$var1" == "$var4" ]]
```

Or with `case`, [as Stéphane Chazelas suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397729/116858), or with a far too complicated loop over the variable names and using a name reference (in `bash` or `ksh93`),

```
for var in var2 var3 var4; do
    typeset -n v="$var"
    if [[ "$var1" == "$v" ]]; then
        # printf '%s has same value as var1\n' "$var"
        found=1
        break
    fi
done

if [[ "$found" -eq 1 ]]; then ...
```